# Music stops after 20 seconds (android soundboard)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have made my own android soundboard.
Now i have only 1 problem
I have a song Intro , but it is about 38 seconds.
When i am trying to play intro i only hear for about 20 seconds.

can someone help me ?

**SoundBoard.java**

```
    package com.soundboard;

import com.soundboard.SoundManager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Soundboard extends Activity {
private SoundManager mSoundManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
    mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
    mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.sound1);
    mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.sound2);
    mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.sound3);
    mSoundManager.addSound(4, R.raw.sound4);
    mSoundManager.addSound(5, R.raw.sound5);
    mSoundManager.addSound(6, R.raw.sound6);
    mSoundManager.addSound(7, R.raw.sound7);
    mSoundManager.addSound(8, R.raw.sound8);
    mSoundManager.addSound(9, R.raw.sound9);
    mSoundManager.addSound(10, R.raw.sound10);
    mSoundManager.addSound(11, R.raw.sound11);
    mSoundManager.addSound(12, R.raw.sound12);
    mSoundManager.addSound(13, R.raw.sound13);
    mSoundManager.addSound(14, R.raw.sound14);
    mSoundManager.addSound(15, R.raw.sound15);
    mSoundManager.addSound(16, R.raw.sound16);
    mSoundManager.addSound(17, R.raw.sound17);
    mSoundManager.addSound(18, R.raw.sound18);
    mSoundManager.addSound(19, R.raw.sound19);
    mSoundManager.addSound(20, R.raw.sound20);
    mSoundManager.addSound(21, R.raw.sound21);
    mSoundManager.addSound(22, R.raw.sound22);
    mSoundManager.addSound(23, R.raw.sound23);
    mSoundManager.addSound(24, R.raw.sound24);
    mSoundManager.addSound(25, R.raw.sound25);
    mSoundManager.addSound(26, R.raw.sound26);
    mSoundManager.addSound(27, R.raw.sound27);
    mSoundManager.addSound(28, R.raw.sound28);
    mSoundManager.addSound(29, R.raw.sound29);
    mSoundManager.addSound(30, R.raw.sound30);
    mSoundManager.addSound(31, R.raw.sound31);
    mSoundManager.addSound(32, R.raw.sound32);
    mSoundManager.addSound(33, R.raw.sound33);
    mSoundManager.addSound(34, R.raw.sound34);
    mSoundManager.addSound(35, R.raw.sound35);
    mSoundManager.addSound(36, R.raw.sound36);

    Button SoundButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound1);
    SoundButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(1);

}
    });       
    Button SoundButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound2);
    SoundButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(2);

}
    });    
    Button SoundButton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound3);
    SoundButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(3);

}
    });    
    Button SoundButton4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound4);
    SoundButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(4);

}
    });    
    Button SoundButton5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound5);
    SoundButton5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(5);

}
    });   
    Button SoundButton6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound6);
    SoundButton6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(6);

}
    });    
    Button SoundButton7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound7);
    SoundButton7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(7);

}
    });
   Button SoundButton8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound8);
   SoundButton8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(8);

}
   });    
    Button SoundButton9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound9);
    SoundButton9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(9);

}
    });    
   Button SoundButton10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound10);
   SoundButton10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(10);

}
   });    
    Button SoundButton11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound11);
    SoundButton11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(11);

}
    });    
    Button SoundButton12 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound12);
    SoundButton12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(12);

}
    });    
   Button SoundButton13 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound13);
   SoundButton13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(13);

}
   });    
    Button SoundButton14 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound14);
    SoundButton14.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mSoundManager.playSound(14);

}
    });    

    Button SoundButton15 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound15);
            SoundButton15.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(15);

        }
    });
            Button SoundButton16 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound16);
            SoundButton16.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(16);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton17 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound17);
            SoundButton17.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(17);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton18 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound18);
            SoundButton18.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(18);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton19 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound19);
            SoundButton19.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(19);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton20 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound20);
            SoundButton20.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(20);

        }
    });    
           Button SoundButton21 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound21);
            SoundButton21.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(21);

        }
   });    
            Button SoundButton22 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound22);
            SoundButton22.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(22);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton23 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound23);
            SoundButton23.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(23);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton24 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound24);
            SoundButton24.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(24);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton25 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound25);
            SoundButton25.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(25);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton26 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound26);
            SoundButton26.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(26);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton27 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound27);
            SoundButton27.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(27);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton28 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound28);
            SoundButton28.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(28);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton29 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound29);
            SoundButton29.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(29);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton30 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound30);
            SoundButton30.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(30);

        }
    });    
            Button SoundButton31 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound31);
            SoundButton31.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(31);

        }
    });
            Button SoundButton32 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound32);
            SoundButton32.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(32);

        }
    });
            Button SoundButton33 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound33);
            SoundButton33.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(33);

        }
    });

            Button SoundButton34 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound34);
            SoundButton34.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(34);

        }
    });

            Button SoundButton35 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound35);
            SoundButton35.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(35);

        }
    });
            Button SoundButton36 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound36);
            SoundButton36.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(36);

        }
            });
}
}
```

**SoundManager.java**

```
    package com.soundboard;

    import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;



    public class SoundManager {

    private  SoundPool mSoundPool; 
    private  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
    private  AudioManager  mAudioManager;
    private  Context mContext;


    public SoundManager()
    {

    }

    public void initSounds(Context theContext) { 
         mContext = theContext;
         mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); 
         mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
         mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);         
    } 

    public void addSound(int Index,int SoundID)
    {
        mSoundPoolMap.put(Index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));

    }

    public void playSound(int index) { 

         int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
         mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f); 
}

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there any warnings or errors in the logcat? IIRC 38 seconds sound long for a soundpool, I think it can only contain 1MB of uncompressed data, you might not be able to successfully load the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason why you're using Soundpool instead of MediaPlayer?

MediaPlayer is much more elegant for this type of media playback.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing that on the main thread and not in a service (recommended for music playback of that length) or a background thread you could be locking up the event thread for too long.  Just a thought.